# Removing an <img> tag from string and placing it in variable where img src location in string can vary

Tags: php, preg-match, strip

I am using drupal and have a variable that contains loads of html.  What I want to do is select the first image that appears in that html, capture the image src so that I can manipulate the image  in other ways and then remove all images from the html.  I should now have a variable containing the captured first image source, and a variable containing the html minus any images.

To place the first image into a variable I have tried -

```
    $texthtml =  $node->teaser;
preg_match('/<img.+src=[\'"](?P<src>.+?)[\'"].*>/i', $texthtml, $image);
echo $image['src'];
```

This works fine so long as the image code follows the following logic - 'img src..'
however thanks to my content management system, some img tags dont place 'src' straight after 'img' such as - 'img class..'.  In this instance the above code only takes the first image that follows the specific order of 'img src..'  How do I do this where the img code can be in any order?

To then remove the image from the original string I am successfully using -

```
 $stripped = $node->teaser;
$stripped = preg_replace("/<img[^>]+\>/i", "(image) ", $stripped); 
echo $stripped;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please reedit your question as it is not clear if you do not really want to extract src part of tag (which would make more sense I think) or really want to just get rid of `img` part

Comment: Don't use regex to parse html!

Comment: WebnetMobile.com - I have re-edited the question, apologies.  Eric, what should I do instead?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use following,

```
preg_match_all('/\<img(.*?)\/\>/', $texthtml, $matches);
```

Comment: Thanks Amar!  This is giving me an array that looks like this - Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => (image here) [1] =>  How do I get the image out of this?  Also curious as to Eric's comment above about not using regex..  Thanks!